# Is there a way to call python3.8 code, from python3.11?

Tags: python-3.x, grpc, ipc, python-3.8, paddle-paddle

I have some code that breaks in python3.11 for some reason, namely paddleocr. I want to integrate it in a program that is otherwise written in python3.11.

Although there is the obvious method of running paddleocr in a web service, and calling it from the rest of the program through that service, or maybe through that method, I am wondering if there is a better method that exists to do this.

In summary, is there a way to call a function in a python3.8 environment from a python3.11 environment, in a more direct manner than creating an API?

Answer (score 1):

Running Python code written for a specific version like `Python 3.8` in an environment/program using `Python 3.11` can indeed pose compatibility issues, especially with libraries (in this case, `paddleocr`) that may have dependencies not yet compatible with newer versions of Python.

While setting up a web service and calling it through an API is a common solution, there is a direct and local way of doing it: You can use Python's subprocess module to run a script with `Python 3.8` from your `Python 3.11` program. This method involves invoking the `Python 3.8` interpreter as a subprocess and then running the necessary Python script or command.

```py
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(["path/to/python3.8", "path/to/script.py", "arg1", "arg2"], capture_output=True, text=True)
print(result.stdout)
```

While this method is more direct than an API, it's somewhat less flexible and can be more challenging to manage, especially for complex interactions.

Notes:

- The above solution using `subprocess` will not work if you are using a virtual environment because the `Python 3.8` executable may not have all the required Python packages installed. Thanks [Bill Huneke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2784303/bill-huneke) for pointing that out.
- Rather than setting up a web service and calling it through an API, implementing a message queue (like RabbitMQ or Kafka) between the two Python environments can be another solution. The `Python 3.11` program sends messages (tasks) to the queue, which are then consumed by a worker running in the `Python 3.8` environment. This method is beneficial if the tasks are asynchronous and do not require immediate response.

Comment: This is technically valid, but is likely not to work correctly if the OP is running their program in a Python virtual environment (e.g. under Poetry, 'mkvenv', etc).  The 3.8 executable that gets run will not be connected to the same collection of Python packages and dependencies.

Comment: @BillHuneke Yes, that is correct. Thanks for pointing that out; I'll add it as a caveat. IMO OP's initial thought about setting up a web service and calling it using an API is a good solution. Maybe even use some message queues if it involves asynchronous processes.

Comment: absolutely.  running subprocess and parsing stdout is rarely a robust, long term solution (which is probably what you are saying too).  I agree that some other type of IPC might be good.  Best solution is probably to address whatever it is that's causing compact issues.  I can't imagine it's that big.  I cannot think of *any* thing that would work in 3.8 that would not in 3.11.  What is it that's failing, @azman?